# Arabic in docxfactory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arabic, docx

I'm trying to use docxfactory c++ library in msvc11 to generate some predefined document with tags. but the problem is I can't inject Arabic text using setClipboardValue. I keep getting an output with some strange text. Anyone have an idea or an alternative solution for my problem?

```
    WordProcessingMerger& l_merger =
    WordProcessingMerger::getInstance();
    l_merger.load("C:/Program Files (x86)/DocxFactory/samples/templates/exercise12.dfw");
    l_merger.setClipboardValue("_header", "PrintDate",(double) l_start);
    l_merger.paste("file");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        l_merger.setClipboardValue("Line", "tag1","أبجد");
        l_merger.setClipboardValue("Line", "tag2","أبجد");
        l_merger.paste("Line");
    }
    l_merger.save("C:/Program Files (x86)/DocxFactory/samples/templates/exercise12_out.docx");
    cout<< "Completed (in "
    << (double) (clock() - l_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
    << " seconds)."
    << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Arabic in unicode (UTF-8) codepage?

DocxFactory defaults to the computer's default codepage which might not be unicode.

Could you try manually setting the codepage -

l_merger.setCodePage("UTF-8");

Thank you,
Alon